# Reader.GetValue date value

Tags: c#, date, time, sqldatareader

I am looping out the `reader.GetValue` from a SQL Server database, all works, however I have a column of data type `Date` in the table. When I view the data in the table, it shows correctly the date '18-Dec-17' with NO time.

The output of the `reader` is of this format: '18-Dec-17 12:00:00 AM' AND all records show 12:00:00 AM the same, regardless of the date change.

Could someone let me know whats going on here and is there an option to remove or do I need to regex or replace it?

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    while (cnt_field <= reader.FieldCount - 1)
    {
        db_output = db_output + "" + reader.GetValue(cnt_field) + " -\t ";
        cnt_field++;
    }//WEND
    cnt_field = 0;
    db_output = db_output + "\n\r";
}//WEND
```

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no `Date` only data type in .NET.

Comment: You cannot change that - SQL Server has a `DATE` datatype which contains date only - .NET does **NOT** have such a type. SQL Server's `DATE` columns are always mapped to .NET `DateTime` and thus *always* include the `00:00:00` time portion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `"" + reader.GetValue(...)` you are doing an implicit `reader.GetValue(...).ToString()`.

What you then see is the default representation of a `DateTime`. dotNET does not have a separate `Date` type.

So you will have to detect DateTime values inside your loop and apply the desired formatting.

Something like

```
while (cnt_field <= reader.FieldCount - 1)
{
   object value = reader.GetValue(cnt_field);
   if (value is DateTime)
     db_output += ((DateTime)value).ToShortDateString();  // apply a std/custom Date format
   else   
      db_output += value.ToString(); 

   db_output += " -\t ";
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The call to `reader.GetValue(cnt_field)` is returning a `DateTime` ("boxed" as an `object`) that represents the date. Now; both in the database and in a `DateTime`, date-time values **do not have a format** - they are just the raw numeric value of the date/time. When you *concatenate* this with a string, the default `.ToString()` is used, which applies your current culture and default format specifier. So: if that *isn't what you intended*: you'll need to tell it what you intended:

```
var when = (DateTime)reader.GetValue(cnt_field);
db_output = db_output + "" + when.ToString(chosenFormat) + " -\t ";
```

You might also want to explicitly specify a culture - `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is usually a good choice for logging etc.

You can choose [standard format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) or [custom format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) to build the format you want. You might want `"dd-MMM-yy"`, so:

```
db_output = db_output + "" + when.ToString("dd-MMM-yy") + " -\t ";
```